# Android can get the cpu usage rate of the process without root

Tags: android

I am working on a performance analysis tool, and I expect to get the cpu usage of other processes through the process number。

But I found that neither the **top** method nor the **/proc/pid/stat** method can get the cpu information of other processes。

I checked other related performance analysis tools, such as Tencent's PerfDog. They claim to be able to analyze without android root privileges. I would like to know if there is any way to obtain the cpu information of the corresponding process without root privileges！

I try

`top -n 1`

My test application USER is system, and this specification is performed in the code. I found that only processes whose USER is system can be obtained.

This is not what I want, I want to get more process information of USER

I try

`/proc/pid/stat`

In the code, I use this instruction to get the cpu information of other processes, and it prompts me java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/9832/stat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

So how can this be avoided. Let me get cpu information of other processes without root privileges